Natural mechanism behind burning oceans
I have an alternate Earth with no humans where massive patches of the oceans are supposed to be burning. The fires do not come from artificial or man-made causes. The flames themselves:

have lasted for millions of years
range from being small to being expansive enough to form massive walls of fire

Is there a possible mechanism arising from nature or natural causes that can be used to explain this phenomena? The answer mustn't make the planet uninhabitable for life

Massive patches is a problem.There are several places that have had hydrocarbons burning for decades. But massive self limits due to depleting global oxidizer levels and allowing cooling to prevent re-ignition.

You've gotten some pretty good answers here, and many of them point out various problems with your requirements.
I'm gonna try and take an alternative approach, which will lead to different problems with your requirements. I'll let you choose which problems you prefer.
The biggest issue here is that with most fires, you're gonna run out of oxidizer pretty soon, which will kill both the fires and most life on the planet. JBH already mentioned burning hydrogen as a solution to this, and this is probably your best bet, as hydrogen is abundant (if not usually in its pure form) and produces water when it burns, which probably won't kill all life (hey, maybe this is how the oceans were made in the first place?)
But there's another alternative here, and what it lacks in realism, it makes up for by being more fun.
It's spelled FOOF, and its great! You might have a hard time explaining what natural process could possibly provide a continuous supply of difluoride-dioxide, but I'm sure you'll think of something, and you don't really need much of it!
the upsides of FOOF are legion: you wont run out of oxidizer, because FOOF is an oxidizer. it's such an efficient oxidizer that almost anything it touches spontaneously catches fire. this includes the oceans themselves!
FOOF is further the only answer to the literal interpretation of your first sentence: oceans are supposed to be burning. With FOOF, it'll actually be the oceans themselves that are burning, not some oilspills that happens to be floating in them!
as for your massive walls of fire? just let loose a bigger blob of FOOF! if you drop a liter of this stuff in the ocean, I for one wouldn't want to be anywhere near it when you do!
The problems here include the previously mentioned unlikeliness of FOOF appearing naturally, and to some extent perhaps also the toxic fumes that will be created after it has caused the oceans to literally burn. Those fumes probably wont make your planet uninhabitable, but they'll sure kill anyone/anything who happens to breath it in. But i think these toxins break down relatively quickly, so most of your planet will probably be fine, for the most part.
for more information of the chemical marvel that is FOOF, theres really only one link on the internet for this that's worth it's salt.

Chlorine trifluoride would also work, and has the advantage that it can exist as a stable(-ish?) liquid at above the freezing point of water.

Let's begin with a Frame Challenge

Massive patches of ocean.
Millions of years.
Small to massive walls of fire.
Inhabitable planet.


When you look at plausible sources of fuel (oil, methane/natural gas, coal, etc.) I believe the largest known source is the Ghawar oil field (8,400 square km). The problem is that "massive patches" when applied to oceanic standards is something pretty large. A 25,000 square km patch in the ocean (almost 3X the size of the Ghawar oil field) is mighty small compared to, e.g., the Atlantic Ocean. So I really don't know what you mean by "massive patches" because a patch as big as the Ghawar oil field (which is a small patch of the ocean in size) is the biggest natural fuel source we know of. And while we're on the subject, let me remind you that oceans have currents. You won't ever have patches, you'll have streamers. Water in the ocean does not stand still so your fire won't, either.

I apologize for being blunt, but why on earth do you need an ocean to burn for millions of years? To the best of my knowledge, there is no fuel source that has ever existed on the planet Earth that could lead to much of anything burning for millions of years. Add to this the fact that it's almost mandatory to have some form of constant ignition source because storms happen. Rain and wind. Even oil, floating on the surface of the water, can be extinguished. A constant burning flame for millions of years isn't just implausible, it's unbelievable. Oceans with oil might be believable, and explorers might learn an important lesson the first time lighting strikes nearby, but that constant burn is a hard nut to swallow. (Final note: it takes time for fuel sources to form and if you're drawing from them as their forming this all becomes outrageously unbelievable. Now, an "earth" that never evolved humanity and/or sapience such that the fuel sources finished forming millions of years ago and then started to burn... still magical, but at least it makes sense... it's just hard to believe nothing evolved intelligence during that time.)

You don't explain what a "massive wall of fire" is. I thought about voting to close the question for lack of details. I have no doubt you understand what you meant by "massive patches" and "massive walls of fire," but they don't have universal meanings and we can't read your mind. If we assume a wall of fire towering one kilometer into the air then we've seriously entered full-on magic mode. If we're talking three to five meters above the water (a "wall" compared to a sailing ship) then I can ignore this issue. So, what's a "massive wall of fire?" (And remember that if you seriously want natural "as realistic as possible" answers you need to have appropriate expectations.)

Finally, I have a problem with the expectation of an inhabitable planet. Combustion has consequences. Millions of years of continent-sized combustion has CONSEQUENCES. While burning hydrogen results in oxygen and water, burning almost anything else results in carbon monoxide or dioxide (IMPORTANT! This means the global free oxygen levels drop... how is that replenished? Better hope the rest of the planet is lush, green jungle). If we walk away from constant millions-of-years burning we enter the world of CONSEquences, which might result in habitability, maybe. If your expectation is fire, as in what you find in your house's fireplace, then we either need to defer to @L.Dutch's answer (using "combustion" in the chemistry sense and not just the forest fire sense) or you need to live with the fact that your world is going to have an atmosphere with a LOT of CO and CO2 in it. And an average world temperature that's higher than average here on Earth (probably even accounting for humanity's predilection for pollution). I'm sorry to say it, and I hope seriously to be proven wrong, but I think "inhabitable planet" is a deal killer.


Let's ignore everything I just said, embrace the science-fiction tag, and change some of your expectations

The burning oceans are recent. They may have started the day before the explorers (my explorers, you didn't explain the point-of-view of any of this) arrived or years or a thousand years before. But not millions. There hasn't been enough time to exhaust the fuel sources, which the world is drawing upon at a massive rate to keep the fires burning, even given what I'm about to say.

The burning is periodic due to changing weather patterns. Lightning starts the fires, wind and rain can (can...) put them out. The explorers may find patches near the larger fuel sources (like a volcanic vent, but it's not volcanic... it's "hydrocarbonic." I'll get to this momentarily...) that constantly burn, but they may also suddenly realize that they're in the middle of an ocean that's turned oddly shiny and rainbow colored... and then one of the explorers decides to put out his coals by flicking the butt into the ocean, followed by the phrase "oh cra....."

I'm having trouble imagining fuel sources that will work other than oil. Coal does float in water and might float well in salt water, but to get what you're looking for it would have to be breaking apart on the ocean floor (or washed in by a river) as dust. It's hard to imagine that much dust. Billions of tons of dust constantly floating into the ocean. Methane and natural gas are contenders, but they don't sit on the ocean surface. @Gillgamesh's idea of microbes is great and I've upvoted the answer because it might be your only hope for even a science-fiction answer that has everything you want (kinda, that inhabitability part is a problem), but an organic solution (microbes) that doesn't have a predator? Not impossible... but after millions of years you'd think something found the little wombats tasty. It's why I'm voting for oil — while some bacteria eat it, the salinity of the ocean rationalizes why they don't. It floats on the water, can exist in vast reserves below the ocean floor, can believably leak to the surface and it will stay there. Which is how I get to "hydrocarbonic" (vs. "volcanic..." Oh, work with me!).

The fire will never be more than about 2 feet off the surface. It takes either a highly volatile fuel source (aka gasoline) or a LOT of fuel source to create a credible wall of fire. The amount of oil (or anything else) coming up from the ocean floor to create a "wall of fire" is breathtaking. BUT! If we change that to a "pillar of fire" from the perspective of the fire directly above the fuel leak, and if the fuel leak is reasonably big, and the current at that point is reasonably weak, and we don't make the pillar too big because we want some of the fuel to float off to burn elsewhere... then I believe we can get to a "pillar of fire." But I can't get to walls of flame with anything less than magic.

Finally, an inhabitable planet would strongly (strongly) suggest that only one ocean has this phenomena — because you need rain and a lot off it to keep most of the rest of the planet cool enough and clean enough for human habitation. Now all that fire has as (another) consequence a heightened amount of evaporation, so you can believably rationalize the extra rain you need to keep the world fit for humanity.


Oil. Good old fashioned oil. Considerably more than Earth has... but what's to say that it's unbelievable?

Millions of years is a big ask. Methane hydrates or hydrocarbon leaks could provide the fuel for burning water. The oldest existing "eternal flame" is a coal seam fire near Mount Wingen, Australia. But that is only ~6000 years old... (only)
Chemosynthetic microbes could produce fuel for fires in the form of Methane hydrates.

Methane hydrate, also known as "fire-ice", is a naturally occurring
frozen form of methane and water that's buried beneath the ocean
floor.

In reality the formation of the hydrates and/or methane is a slow process. However with just a little nudge into the direction of sci-fi. A microbe could be imagined to be hyper efficient at producing the fuels needed to achieve your goals.
To add a layer of complexity to the scenario you could add some fuel for the microbes to feast upon and offset the greenhouse gasses created by the fires etc. There is a plant that is supposed to perhaps be responsible from pulling the climate out of the PETM (Paleocene-Eocene Thermal Maximum). The Azolla fern grows fast, dies, sinks to the ocean bottom where the microbes convert it into methane gasses to produce the flames. Read about the Azolla Event.

It wasn't exactly burning oceans, but something similar happened on Earth during the Great Oxidation Event:

The Great Oxidation Event (GOE) or Great Oxygenation Event, also called the Oxygen Catastrophe, Oxygen Revolution, Oxygen Crisis or Oxygen Holocaust, was a time interval during the Earth's Paleoproterozoic era when the Earth's atmosphere and shallow seas first experienced a rise in the concentration of free oxygen. This began approximately 2.460–2.426 Ga (billion years) ago during the Siderian period and ended approximately 2.060 Ga ago during the Rhyacian.
The GOE is inferred to have been caused by cyanobacteria, which evolved chlorophyll-based photosynthesis that releases dioxygen as a byproduct of water photolysis. The continually produced oxygen eventually depleted all the surface reducing capacity from ferrous iron, sulfur, hydrogen sulfide and atmospheric methane over nearly a billion years. The oxidative environmental change, compounded by a global glaciation, devastated the microbial mats around the Earth's surface.

It lasted 400 million year and, in a chemical sense, a combustion is an oxidation.
You might have something similar.

"Mustn't make the planet uninhabitable by life" kind of writes this off, since the Great Oxidation didn't result in much free oxygen for metabolism during those 400Ma.

@jdunlop we are still here after that, and there was life before and after it. Metabolism doesn't need exclusively oxygen

But it's not "after" or "before" that the OP is concerned with, but during.  And I am skeptical that single-celled life is what the OP is talking about.  I'm sure complex life is possible with metabolic pathways that don't use oxygen as their electron receptor, but the event you're describing is part and parcel with an evolutionary pathway that does.

I think the event lasted around ~200my. Also the oxidization occurred in many pulses, where o2 built up... killed all the life that o2 was a poison and collapsed again, this is partly the origin of the great banded iron formations.

The amount of oxidation that occured all those eons ago is beyond all contemplation. There is now so much oxygen in the atmosphere that even combusting the entire biosphere would have very little effect on the oxygen content of the atmosphere.

What about St. Elmo's Fire? Ok, it's not actual fire, it's plasma. but it's close enough. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23469/is-fire-plasma
These coronal ejections are generated by discharges of electrically charged objects. Now, without too much hand waving, we can explain why large swathes of your oceans have had the presence of electric charges for long periods (millions of years). They are near the poles, there are charged deposits near the surface, there is ionization due to some radioactive mechanism near the surface, and so on..
Then above these areas the air would become ionized and depending of the composition of your atmosphere it could certainly look like fire (orange-blue). Note that saint Elmo's fire on earth glows green.
Depending on what is causing this ionization, you could have beautiful, but harmless lightshows akin to our auroras, or deadly swirls of high speed plasma following magnetic curves that would be like, but not quite as energetic, as solar flares.

This could certainly look great! I wonder if this can cause electrolysis in the seas it hangs above. That most certainly could create a flammable gas.

@AndersMartini's answer got me thinking...
and I upvoted Ander's answer because FOOF is a whale of a good idea because there's so much crisis that can be rationalized due to it. It's a great idea... but his answer got me thinking.
Introducing Oklo, a naturally occurring fission nuclear reactor
As in a rock that sits there and generates energy via nuclear fission due to an abnormally high concentration of U-235. And why does it work as a nuclear reactor rather than burning itself out quickly? Because of the presence of water.
So let's say a meteor shower deposited U-235 in such a way that it created large patches of dense deposits on the ocean floor. This would rationalize the release of hydrogen by splitting the ocean water.
You can have a LOT of fun by bringing a molten salt reactcor explanation into it allowing the reaction to last longer. I love the science-fiction tag. So what we have is a heat source at the bottom of the ocean that's hot enough to split ocean water into its components: hydrogen, oxygen, and sodium (at least).
Don't ask me how you get from atomic sodium at the bottom of an ocean next to a natural fission reactor to liquid sodium. Just nod appreciatively at the flow chart box that reads "magic happens here" and keep reading.
You still have problems in that:

They hydrogen won't stay on the ocean surface. That means you're burning the higher concentration at the surface, but it will nevertheless (over long periods of time) result in a higher hydrogen percentage in the atmosphere. But at least you don't have runaway global warming.

It does permit your "massive walls" in that the burning process can carry to height, but it wouldn't be particularly universal. It would happen where a particularly large and/or dense bubble of hydrogen rises from the ocean floor.

You still have the problem of ignition sources. Hydrogen is flammable, but it won't self-combust. If you rationalize a lot of hydrogen bubbles due to the natural reactor, then you could have flame "racing" around the ocean surface from one bubble to the next.

Thanks to that natural fission reactor your ocean will have a higher temperature. That's going to impact habitability, too. It'll also impact global weather. This planet would be very wet methinks.


I'm still favoring oil, but this could be fun, too.
